# Find maximum value of function

Tags: functions

I have to analyse the following function

$F(b, k) = \frac{ab(k-1)}{k(1-ab)}$, given $a$ is a constant, $0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1$; $k > 1$ and $kb < 1$.

So I need to find $b$ and $k$, or the relationship between $b$ and $k$ to get the the maximum value of $F(b, k)$. I've tried for two days but it doesn't seem easy to me. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the partial derivatives of $$F = \frac{ab(k-1)}{k(1-ab)}$$ after some trivial simplifications, you get $$F'_b=\frac{a (k-1)}{k (a b-1)^2}$$ $$F'_k=\frac{a b}{k^2(1-a b)}$$ So, if $a \neq 0$, these partials cancel for $k=1$ and $b=0$ but this does not correspond to a maximum value.

It seems to me that the maximum value corresponds to $b=1$ and to the largest value of $k$ we can consider.

**This answer was written before appears the condition $k b \lt 1$ in the post.**

Comment: but $0 < b < 1$, so does it mean that there is no maximum value?

Comment: and sorry, I just added $bk < 1$ to the condition.

Comment: This makes the story different ! Let me look at the problem again.

Comment: put $bk=1$, it should solve he problem as $b,k $ get max, $f$ get max.